# What is happening if I changed dropna to True/False

Tags: python, pandas

if i write this code:

```
train['id_03'].value_counts(dropna=False, normalize =True).head()
```

I am getting

```
NaN    0.887689233582822
0.0    0.108211128797372
1.0    0.001461374335354
3.0    0.001131168083449
2.0    0.000712906831036
Name: id_03, dtype: float64
```

If i changed dropna =True

I get

```
0.0    0.963497
1.0    0.013012
3.0    0.010072
2.0    0.006348
5.0    0.001643
Name: id_03, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I wanna know, that if dropna removes null values what Is causing other values to change ? Shouldn't all of the other should remain the same ?

Comment: Normalize is the issue, its normalising based on remaining values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is that you specified `normalize =True` It is: `"If True then the object returned will contain the relative frequencies of the unique values."` according to the documentations.

Before you removed Na's the Na's counts are used to calculate the relative frequencies, after you removed them, the denominator of the relative frequencies changed, hence values changed

Answer (score 1):

You are normalising the result. The value for the `NaN` would appear to be very large with respect to the others. Hence the other indexes result in very small numbers

If you look at the relative ratio between indexes 1 & 2 you'll see that they are equivalent in both results.

Comment: Yes, I see them now